# Youtube controls (play/pause) don't work after player is restored/activity is resumed

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have an activity with a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` within it to play youtube videos.

The youtube player's style is set to `CHROMELESS` (only video, no controls), and playback is controlled by my own custom play/pause button outside of the player's view. Every thing works as expected until the moment I leave the video activity for whatever reason and then come back to it.

Upon leaving the activity the video is paused - as expected - but after returning to it, requesting the player to `player.play()` does nothing. No errors nor exceptions, it just does nothing. `Play()` will only work again after I load a new video..

I've trying using `YouTubePlayerFragment` instead, but the result is the same. However, when using the `DEFAULT` style pressing the default play button will apparently reload the video (I see the buffer being flushed) from the previous position and work as expected. This leads me to believe that they're handling it somehow directly on their UI control code instead of on the player API..

I can reproduce this issue on the SDK's custom controls sample just by starting a video, pressing the recents key and returning to it so I think it's safe to assume that this is a bug..
Has anyone been able to work around this issue? is there any way to detect that the video needs to be reloaded while this isn't fixed?

Info: I'm using youtube's android player API v1.2.2 and the latest youtube app v10.49.59

Answer (score 0):

After hours, the only solution I found was to save video position on Pause event and reload video (player.loadVideo) on PostResume event (when YouTubeFragment is resumed). But I don't known if this is the only/best solution.